# How do I change the size of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, interface-builder

Is it possible to change the size of the collection view cell without doing it programmatically?

If I try just dragging the size of the cell or adding height and width values, nothing happens in the simulator.

I can resize the image in the cell, but since the cell itself doesn't change, it just clips the image... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a collection view's cell size inside the collection view's **Size inspector**.

[image: The Size inspector view of a collection view]

If you want to set a custom size to a cell, set **Size** to **Custom** in its **Size inspector** and enter an arbitrary value.

[image: The Size inspector of a collection view cell]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Many thanks! :) Didn't know there was a size inspector for collection view :)